# How can I eliminate code repetition while setting control visibility?

Tags: c#

I have 4 text boxes ,i write 4 functions ,in each function i want one textbox to be visible true others false.

```
function1()
{
    Txtbox1.visible=true;
    Txtbox2.visble=false;
    Txtbox3.visible=false;
    TxtBox4.visible=false;
}
```

similarly i write 3 more function to make other text boxes visibility to true.How to do code optimization  c#,Asp.net

Answer (score 4):

Set up an `TextBox` array. Such as

```
TextBox[] textboxes = { TxtBox1, TxtBox2, TxtBox3, TxtBox4 };
```

Then you can write a function to set visibility by index.

```
void SetVisibility(int index)
{
    // do index validation 

    textboxes[index].Visible = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != index) textboxes[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

So now instead of calling `function1(), function()2, // etc.`, you would call `SetVisibility(0), SetVisibility(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Write one function that sets all 4 controls visible to false, then sets the desired control (passed as a parameter) to true:

```
private void ShowTextBox(TextBox target)
{
    Txtbox1.Visible = false;
    Txtbox2.Visible = false;
    Txtbox3.Visible = false;
    Txtbox4.Visible = false;
    target.Visible = true;
}
```

Then call the function passing in the textbox instance you want to be visible:

```
ShowTextBox(Txtbox1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others, you could also use LINQ to do this a couple of different ways.

```
TextBox[] allTextBoxes = { TxtBox1, TxtBox2, TxtBox3, TxtBox4 };

void SetVisibility(TextBox visibleTextBox)
{
    allTextBoxes.Except(new TextBox[] { visibleTextBox })
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(t => t.Visible = false);

    visibleTextBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Usage:

```
SetVisibility(Txtbox1);
```

You could also do it so that you can set multiple (or none, so all are hidden) visible simultaneously (there are still even more ways to do this):

```
void SetVisibility1(params TextBox[] visibleTextBoxes)
{
    var visibleList = visibleTextBoxes.ToList();

    foreach (TextBox t in allTextBoxes)
    {
        t.Visible = visibleList.Contains(t);
    }
}

void SetVisibility2(params TextBox[] visibleTextBoxes)
{
    allTextBoxes.Except(visibleTextBoxes).ToList().ForEach(t => t.Visible = false);
    visibleTextBoxes.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Visible = true);
}

void SetVisibility3(params TextBox[] visibleTextBoxes)
{
    var visibleList = visibleTextBoxes.ToList();
    allTextBoxes.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Visible = visibleList.Contains(t));
}
```